# How to know what is the maximum supported resolution by my GPU?

Tags: graphics-card, resolution, gpu, amd-radeon

Is there any general way to know what is the maximum supported resolution by any GPU? For example my GPU is `AMD radeon HD 8600/8700M max resolution`, and I googled about that information, but I could not find anything helpful. How can I get these information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first result on Google for `AMD radeon HD 8600/8700M` is this page:

http://www.amd.com/en-gb/products/graphics/notebook/8700m-8800m

It includes a link to a [PDF document](http://www.amd.com/Documents/AMD-Radeon-HD-8000M-Series-GPU-Specs.pdf) for full specifications for the entire 8000 series GPU.

In said PDF, it gives you the following information:

- DisplayPort 1.2
  Max resolution: 4096x2160 per display
  HBR2 support
  Multi-Stream Transport
  21.6 Gbps bandwidth
  High bit-rate audio
  Quad FullHD/4k video support
- HDMI® (With 4K, 3D, x.v.Color™ and Deep Color)
  Max resolution: 4096x2160
  1080p60 Stereoscopic 3D
  Quad FullHD/4k video support
- Dual-link DVI with HDCP
  Max resolution: 2560x1600
- VGA
  Max resolution: 2048x1536

Comment: But this seems to be a different version right? or am I missunderstanding something?

Comment: How do you figure?  You told us which model of GPU and the linked information is applicable to that model. Do you have a 8600M or 8700M update your question. We can only go off what you tell us.  Inaccurate information is unhelpful.

Comment: The model I have written in the question is exactly what is written in my device manager.

Comment: Device manager isn’t displaying the exact model you have.  Use more accurate methods to determine precisely which GPU you have.  Research those methods before you ask “how”.

Comment: This answer is accurate and answers your question.

Comment: @Ramhound, searching again, the model I mentioned is exactly the correct model that I have (at least I could not find anything else).